# Spring boot ResourceUtils read file content is giving Path Traversal vulnerability

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, checkmarx

I am building a spring boot application where i need to read json files for my component tests. I have a utility method which takes the name of the file and reads the content using ResourceUtils. Here is the code:

```
public static String getContent(String path) throws IOException {
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(MyTest.class.getResource(path));
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    return content;
  }
```

The checkmarx is reporting the above code as "This may cause a Path
Traversal vulnerability."
How to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this example for path traversal vulnerability [Path Traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal)

To fix this change it something like

```
private static final String BASE_PATH ="/yourbasepath/somewherewherefileisstored";

public static String getContent(String path) throws IOException {
   File file = new File(BASE_PATH, path);
   if (file.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(BASE_PATH)){
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    return content;
  }
  else{
    //throw some error
 }
 }
```

Comment: thanks. I found that by Googling, however i wanted to know is there any better way to do it.